# Random Number with Java

Tags: java

I really want some Java that randomizes from 1-2 and all that I came up with (Doesn't work either) is:

```
random.math (int.1+2)
```

Might actually look stupid to an expert but yeah

Comment: `Math.random() + 1;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just wanting to flip between two integers, You can utilize a ternary operator and the `Math.random()` static method to achieve the desired results:

```
Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 2 : 1
```

Comment: Question seems to indicate that an `int` value is desired, and if you cast that to `int`, you'll only ever get the number `1`, not a random mixture of 1's and 2's.

Comment: Yeah my poor little brain breaks from Jav

Comment: @Andreas Good point, updated to reflect the desired integer results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11672895)

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm confused, how does this not provide an answer to the question? OP was asking for a java expression that randomly returned either `1` or `2`.

Comment: At the time of my review, it was a comment asking OP whether a code snippet works.  Now it has been rephrased as an answer, it's worthy of an upvote (and has one from me).

Comment: BTW, a related (but far from idiomatic) alternative: `(int)(Math.random() + 1.5)`.  The sum is equally likely to fall in the range [1.5, 2.0) or the range [2.0, 2.5), which, after truncation, yield 1 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use the [`Random.nextInt(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method, which will generate an integer between `0` and `n-1`, inclusive.

Here is an example:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    int number = rnd.nextInt(2) + 1;
    System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1
```